# passing parameter in result type="stream" struts2 action

Tags: struts2

How can I pass the parameter value in the result type="stream" action?

```
       <action name="print" class="mypty.EntryAction" method="print">
            <result name="pdf-stream-result" type="stream">
                <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">filename=${generatedPDFFileName}</param>
                <param name="entryId">entryId=${entryId}</param>
           </result>
                <result name="input">/entry.jsp</result>
            </action>

        <action name="editEntry" class="mypty.EntryAction" method="editEntry">
            <result>/Entry.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

I am trying to call the action via javascript from Entry.jsp page.

```
function print1()
    {
        var w = 1024;
        var h = 800;
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        var url="print.action";
        var uploadWindow = window.open (url, 'PrintPopUp', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=0, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
        uploadWindow.focus();
    }
```

If I call this action like below, I can get the entryId from the print action. No need to pass the value.

```
function print()
    {
        //print function
        document.chooseDates.action = 'print.action';
        document.chooseDates.submit();
    }
```

I want to pass the value of **entryId** to the print action. *I can see the value of entryId in the previous action. This print action is called when clicking on the button.* But when print action is called, the entryID value becomes 0. Both action classes have getters and setters for entryId. Is there anyway to pass those value?

Comment: sorry, but not able to understand your question.can you describe it a bit more

Comment: @PTY trying to access the value defined in the previous action.

Comment: @PTY : in your `print()` function you are submitting the for and value is going to action while `print1()`, its not happening like this.Why don't you pass the value in query parameter like `print.action?entryId=entryId`

Comment: yah. I totally forgot that point. thanks. it works now :). could you include that point in ur answer. so I can accept it.

Comment: @Umesh we solve it by request parameters as but what happens if somebody modifies it. can you please comment on this?

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV: i am nor sure what you mean by modify?

Comment: I'm mean there a possibility of changing request parameter by the end user that's I'm trying to convey.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV yes. user can modify entryId value in the url which can lead awkward things happening. I tired both of Umesh's answer and ur answer , both work. I have learned a lot. Thanks you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the action execution is done all objects in the valuestack will be nullified, if you want to access data from provious action you can use following

1. Using [chain interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/chaining-interceptor.html)
2. Use session

Comment: Hi, I used both methods. but I still can't get the value of entryId. I also set session value before call print method like req.setAttribute("entryId",entryId). and call that attribute from my print method. but still get 0 as value. Any missing steps?

Comment: you setting to request attribute, you supposed to set to session object.

Comment: yes. it works.one thing: if I use session, need to avoid confusing sessions. So I clear the session before setting a new value. Thanks.